# MySQL aggr value grouped by json keys

Tags: mysql, json, group-by, mysql-5.7

How to aggregate values of JSON grouped by JSON keys? 
MYSQL version : 5.7.12

table -

```
+------+--------------------------------------+
| col1 | col2                                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
| PPP  | {"A": 0, "B": 5, "C": 10}            |
| SSS  | {"A": 5}                             |
| KKK  | {"A": 5, "B": 5, "C": 10}            |
| KKK  | {"C": 20, "B": 5}                    |
+------+--------------------------------------+
```

output -

```
+------+--------------------------------------+
| col1 | col2                                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
| PPP  | {"A": 0, "B": 5, "C": 10}            |
| SSS  | {"A": 5}                             |
| KKK  | {"A": 5, "B": 10, "C": 30}           |
+------+--------------------------------------+
```

col2 can have any keys for example D, K, L, N etc.

JSON_MERGE_PATCH can help but it is not available in this mysql version? Can someone help in this?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Anycase - parse to separate rows, aggregate, reconstruct JSON. For version 5.7.12 - JSON_TABLE unavailable, so stored procedure with common string parsing recommended.

Comment: What is max. amounts of key-value pairs in `col2`?

Comment: approx 10 key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

The solution for not more than 5 key-value pairs per JSON (may be easily expanded):

```sql
SELECT col1, JSON_OBJECTAGG(`key`, `value`) col2
FROM (
SELECT col1,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(col2), CONCAT('$[', numbers.num, ']'))) `key`,
       SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(col2, CONCAT('$.', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(col2), CONCAT('$[', numbers.num, ']')))))) `value`
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (          SELECT 0 num
            UNION ALL SELECT 1 
            UNION ALL SELECT 2 
            UNION ALL SELECT 3 
            UNION ALL SELECT 4 ) numbers
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING `key` IS NOT NULL
) subquery
GROUP BY col1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=918c8697d66280370c02f2e49d12eed6) (contains solution building steps).